# jupyter notebook axis printing blackout all values in matplotlib pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I was working in Jupyter notebook with matplotlib on a macbook pro. I sent the file to my other computer and the output changed and I have no clue what the problem is or how to fix it.

It appears like it it trying to plot all the values on the axis, but again I did not change any code. See screenshot.

[Picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NonJ2.png)

Anyone know what I did wrong? 
This next the picture of what I usually see and what I expected as an example...

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DcLR.png)

Comment: Can you also post the plot that you were expecting.

Comment: I just opened up a new notebook, for the example screenshot attached...and it works as usual. So, I'm wondering why it changed all of a sudden because it worked before no problem.

Comment: You seem to be plotting strings instead of dates or numbers. Don't use strings to plot!

Comment: Yeah, i guess that could be correct... i had to use "y = np.asarray(y, dtype="|S6")" for the MLPClassifier in sklearn... Odd it popped up after i switched machines.